# F# Deserialize JSON to string or node

Tags: json, f#, json.net

I have some JSON data I am trying to deserialize that looks like so:

```
{[{ 
  "node":"xyz",
  "type":"string"
 },
 {
  "node":{ "moredata":"values", "otherdata":"values2" },
  "type":"node"
 }]}
```

I want to be able to serialize this to a F# class but it currently fails because the node field can change type. Does anyone know a good way of handling this? I assume I want the node field to be something like a JsonNode type?
I am currently using Newtonsoft but open to using other libraries if there is a better solution in one of them.

EDIT: Unfortunately, I can't use type providers because I want this to be usable from C#.

Comment: See https://github.com/xyncro/chiron or https://github.com/mausch/Fleece

Comment: What do you want it to look like from C#?

Comment: Just a standard POCO with the type providers there was no itellisense. If there is a way around this I'm all ears.

Comment: @DanielSlater Which CLR type should a `Node` property or field have?

Comment: See the answer I put below, very happy to unmark it as answered if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the current solution I'm using:

```
type Object = {
    node : Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken
    ``type`` : string
}

let data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Object[]>(jsonStr)
```

This at least allows me to load the object and have some type safety while not losing any data.

But my ideal solution would allow me to have something like node : ICommonInterface
And then the underlying type will be a type for each datatype.

Comment: Not a flexible solution. Strong binding to the type JToken

Comment: I'm happy to hear a better one

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [JSON Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html). It understands heterogeneous node types. Here's the JSON from the OP (corrected, so that it's valid JSON), used as a sample to define a type:

```
open FSharp.Data

type MyJson = JsonProvider<"""{
    "arr": [
        {
            "node": "xyz",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "moredata": "values",
                "otherdata": "values2"
            },
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
}""">
```

You can now create a value of that type by calling `MyJson.Parse`, but if you only want to look at the JSON used as the example from which the type is inferred, you can also use `GetSample`:

```
let json = MyJson.GetSample()
```

Now you can start exploring the data. Here's an FSI session:

```
> json.Arr;;
val it : JsonProvider<...>.Arr [] =
  [|{
  "node": "xyz",
  "type": "string"
};
    {
  "node": {
    "moredata": "values",
    "otherdata": "values2"
  },
  "type": "node"
}|]

> json.Arr |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Node);;
val it : JsonProvider<...>.StringOrNode [] =
  [|"xyz"; {
  "moredata": "values",
  "otherdata": "values2"
}|]
```

As you can see, each `Node` is a `StringOrNode` value, which you can access like this:

```
> json.Arr |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Node.Record) |> Array.choose id;;
val it : JsonProvider<...>.Node [] =
  [|{
  "moredata": "values",
  "otherdata": "values2"
}|]
```

Since `x.Node.Record` is an `option`, you can select only those that are `Some` with `Array.choose`.

You can get the strings in a likewise way:

```
> json.Arr |> Array.map (fun x -> x.Node.String) |> Array.choose id;;
val it : string [] = [|"xyz"|]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer, but I should have specified. I can't use type providers because I want this to be usable from C#. I had this working with type providers before, but had to throw that out for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the FSharp.Data JSON parser (not the type provider but the parser)?  If you define the class yourself you can use the parser to iterate through the properties and populate the class.

http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html

Here's a working example.

```
open System
open FSharp.Data
open FSharp.Data.JsonExtensions

let json = """{
    "arr": [
        {
            "node": "xyz",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "moredata": "values",
                "otherdata": "values2"
            },
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
}"""

type Node = 
    | String of string
    | Complex of string*string
    with 
    static member Parse (json:JsonValue) =
        match json with
        | JsonValue.String (s) -> String(s)
        | JsonValue.Record (r) ->            
            r 
            |> Map.ofArray // Map<string,JsonValue>
            |> fun m -> Complex(m.["moredata"].AsString(),m.["otherdata"].AsString())
        | _ -> raise (new Exception("Can't parse"))

type Simple = 
    { Node:Node; Type:string}
    with 
    static member Parse (json:JsonValue) =
        // ideally we'd use json?node and json?type to access the properties, but since type is a reserved word.
        {Node=Node.Parse(json?node); Type=json.GetProperty("type").AsString()}


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let s= 
        json
        |> JsonValue.Parse
        |> fun j -> 
            seq { for v in j?arr do yield Simple.Parse v}
        |> Array.ofSeq

    printfn "%A" s
    0
```

Output:

```
[|{Node = String "xyz";
   Type = "string";}; {Node = Complex ("values","values2");
                       Type = "node";}|]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can fit something like this:

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

open System.Linq

let json = """{
    "arr": [
        {
            "node": "xyz",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "moredata": "values",
                "otherdata": "values2"
            },
            "type": "node"
        }
    ]
}"""

type Simple = {
    Node : string
    Type : string
}

JObject.Parse(json).["arr"]
                   .Children()
                   .Select(fun (x:JToken) -> 
                            {Node = string (x.ElementAt 0) ; Type = string (x.ElementAt 1)})
                   .ToList()
                   .ForEach(fun x -> printfn "Type: %s\nNode:\n%s" x.Type x.Node)
```

Print:

```
Type: "type": "string"
Node:
"node": "xyz"
Type: "type": "node"
Node:
"node": {
  "moredata": "values",
  "otherdata": "values2"
}
```

Link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3G1hXl

But it's in the style of C#. Not good for F#